# Application.Check spelling not returning correct Boolean value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to prepare a excel file which automatically shows if any word is misspelled. There are codes that shows and highlights the particular word field when word is misspelled ,however I want to highlight a different cell if **any**
of the words are misspelled.

This is what I did:-

```
Function GFD() As Boolean

Application.CheckSpelling (Range("a1").Text)

End Function

'=======================================================

Function GFF() As Boolean

Application.CheckSpelling (Range("a2").Text)

End Function
```

Problem is in the function I am not getting correct value, if I write "asdfsd" in a2 the function is set as False ,which is correct. But if I write "perfect" which is correct, it again returns False.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the function to the value returned by the application:

```
Function GFD() As Boolean
  GFD = Application.CheckSpelling(Range("a1").Text)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks :) really helpful. I am amateur programmer with no VBA training ,so this helps me a lot.